# Hidden Logic errors in code?

Tags: rust

My goal here is to find the first triangular number with 500 divisors, from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12). This is what I have so far:

```
use std::num::Float;

fn main() {
    let mut num = vec!(1 , 3 , 6 , 10);
    let mut a = 0us;
    let mut fac = vec![];
    for _ in (0us..1000000us) {
        let x =
            num[num.len() - 1] - num[num.len() - 2] + 1 +
                num[num.len() -
                        1]; //extremely clever way of listing triangle numbers(not to be cocky :))
        num.push(x);
    }
    println!("{:?}" , num);
    println!("Calculating...");
    let mut _i = 1is;
    for _ in (0us..num.len() as usize) {
        for _ in (1us..(num[a] as f64).sqrt() as usize) {                                        //Logic Error
            if num[a] % _i == 0 { fac.push(_i); }
            //print!("{},\n" , res.len()); }
            _i += 1;
        }
        fac.push(num[a] as isize,);
        if fac.len() >= 10 {println!("Length: {}\nVector: {:?}\nValue: {}\n\nYOU GOT THE ANSWER! WOOT! \x07", fac.len(), fac, num[a]); break;}
        _i = 1;
        fac = vec![];
        a+=1
    }
}
```

but this prints '864864000' as the value which isn't correct, which doesn't make sense to me, I have tried `499`(since the vector doesn't include the number itself) and `501` and `502` and I get the same number.

P.S: please don't try to make my code look cleaner or propose the closed form formula, as I'm trying to do this with my bare brain, which now needs a bit of help :)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but I get "YOU GOT THE ANSWER! WOOT!" when I run this. Does that not mean that your code worked? Your example says that `864864000` isn't correct, but what *is* correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your errors are coming from converting a very large integer to f32 and then comparing (which loses accuracy)

Comment: Same output when took off the f32's.

Answer (score 0):

When computing divisors, you cannot stop at the square root of the number.  At best, you could stop at `n/i` where `n` is the number you are counting the divisors of, and `i` is the lowest divisor greater than 1.

For example, when counting the divisors of 12, you would only try dividing by 1, 2 and 3, which would give you a divisor count of 4 instead of six, since it misses that 4 and 6.  This results in you finding many fewer divisors than the numbers actually have.

Possibly this comes from the vector holding the divisors being called `fac` which suggests that they are factors instead of divisors.